# Probability of products when rolling 2 dice

Tags: probability

If you roll two six-sided dice twenty times, what is the probability that the product of the two numbers will be an odd number?

Comment: Your question confuses me. You roll the dice 20 times, yet you want the product of just two numbers? Which two? If it's just what comes up on one roll for either die, the rolling 20 times is irrelevant. If not, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

The make the product odd, the two multiplicand must be odd

The probability of odd product in single roll will be $\dfrac36\cdot\dfrac36$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\end{align}
$$
\overbrace{1 \over 36}^{\pars{\dsc{1,1}}}+
\overbrace{1 \over 36}^{\pars{\dsc{3,3}}}+
\overbrace{1 \over 36}^{\pars{\dsc{5,5}}}+
2\times\overbrace{1 \over 36}^{\pars{\dsc{1,3}}}+
2\times\overbrace{1 \over 36}^{\pars{\dsc{1,5}}}+ 
2\times\overbrace{1 \over 36}^{\pars{\dsc{3,5}}}=9\times{1 \over 36}
=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 4}} 
$$